# How can array be an index in python?

Tags: python, numpy, keras, neural-network

I can't understand this line "**results[i, sequence] = 1.**"
How can "sequence" be an index if it is an array, not number. Its shape in these 2 examples is (25000,). What actually occurs in this line?

```
from keras.datasets import imdb
(train_data, train_labels), (test_data, test_labels) = imdb.load_data(
num_words=10000)

import numpy as np

def vectorize_sequences(sequences, dimension = 10000):
    results = np.zeros((len(sequences), dimension))
    for i, sequence in enumerate(sequences):
        results[i, sequence] = 1.
    return results

x_train = vectorize_sequences(train_data)
x_test = vectorize_sequences(test_data)
```

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing

Comment: Read on [integer-array-indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing)

Comment: A related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68422410/standard-implementation-of-vectorize-sequences